# ddrescue image can't be mounted

Tags: ddrescue

I am trying to recover the data from an external HDD for a friend.

I am using Knoppix latest version booting it from USB.

I created an image (.img) using a tutorial for `ddrescue`, but now I have the `copia.img` file and can't mount it.

If I try to mount the terminal says:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on .....
```

The drive was used to storage photos and does not contain any OS or similar.

If I run File command to the copia.img file it says:

> DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x52+2, OEM-ID "NTFS", Media
>   descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 63, dos
>   <4.0 BootSector (0x80), FAT (1Y biy by descriptor);NTFS, sectors/track
>   63, sectors 1953520001, $MFT start cluster 21931768, $MFTMirror start
>   cluster 477176, clusters/RecordSgement 2, clusters/index block 8,
>   serial number 0d2c6a522c6a507b5; contains Microsoft Windows XP/Vista
>   bootloader BOOTMGR

Also, if I run dmesg command it says:

[image]

Please can you please help me recovering it?

Comment: What does `file copia.img` say? What is the `mount` command you are using (I assume you are mounting through a loop device, but it's best if we can see exactly)?

Comment: @dhag i use "mount -o loop,ro copia.img mountpoint but it says:mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on .....

Comment: What does file `copia.img` say?

Comment: i don't understand what you are asking me...sorry i'm very noob in Linux @dhag

Comment: It means "please run the command `file copia.img` in a terminal and edit your question to add this and its output".

Comment: Also, what type of file system did the original hard drive contain? There are several things that could have happened wrong, and knowing what `file` says could help narrow them down (for example, if you copied a whole device, then it is not the same as copying a single partition from it).

Comment: @dhag just edited the question with the File comand result. It contains photos (this is the info my friend gives me), and i think only one partition. I just copied the whole device i think). It is an external HDD

Answer (score 6):

From the output of your call to `file`, it appears that your file is
an image of a whole block device, containing several partitions,
rather than a single filesystem. This explains why `mount` could not
mount it: that command supports mounting single filesystems.

To mount a filesystem that is within a disk image, you have to:

1. run `fdisk -l` on the image to find the file system offsets;
2. compute `<offset> * <block size>` to get the offset in bytes;
3. create a loop device from the file at that offset;
4. mount using that loop device explicitly.

I'm taking excerpts from
https://web.archive.org/web/20170917154947/http://madduck.net/blog/2006.10.20:loop-mounting-partitions-from-a-disk-image/
which has complete instructions; this could look like:

```
$ /sbin/fdisk -lu disk.img
[...]
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
[...]
disk.imgp7        10860003    68372639    28756318+  83  Linux

# losetup /dev/loop0 disk.img -o $((10860003 * 512))
# file -s /dev/loop0
/dev/loop0: Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data
# mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
[...]
# umount /mnt
# losetup -d /dev/loop0
```

That same blog post indicates that a newer package named "kpartx" may
be able to automate the computation.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying but it does not run. `fdisk` shows "Unidades: sectores de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes", and `/media/sdf1/Copia/copia.img` starts at `539915109`, but when I try to run `losetup /dev/loop0 /media/sdf1/Copia/copia.img -o $((539915109 * 512))` I get "losetup: /media/sdf1/Copia/copia.img: error al configurar dispositivo de bucle: Dispositivo o recurso ocupado" (Device or resource occupied)

Comment: i can see that there are 4 partitions but when i try the losetup command it says that device is occuped

Comment: The device loop0 may have been created by your first attempt; either release it, or try with e.g. loop1.

Comment: Seems that now runs. When tipe command File -s /dev/loop0 it shows "data". But when i try mount /dev/loop0 /mnt it shows an error. Says that codepage or auxiliar program lacks or another error. Incorrect file system type, incorrect option...

Comment: I just executed the command parted and it only shows 1 partition. Start 0B and ends 1000202241023B in NTFS.

Comment: The kpartx hint is very useful. I followed these instructions, https://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/mounting-raw-image-files-and-kpartx/ , and mounted the inner filesystem with only a couple commands.